# Setting up CDN in a linux server

Tags: nginx, cdn, digital-ocean, server-administration, content-delivery-network

I'm trying to set up a CDN for my website. I've hosted it in my virtual server on Digital Ocean but I can't find an howto for configuring all the necessary. Have anyone some suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest something like:

- **nginx** server (very fast for static assets and has a very low memory usage)
- **varnish** for cache (HTTP accelerator)

Your most requested static assets like **css**, **js** or **images** will be cached and served 
as fast as a lightning. I'd recommend having at least 1GB or 2GB of ram for better results.

Here are some helpful links:

How to install nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin

Install varnish: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-clustered-web-server-with-varnish-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-13-10

I guess this will serve your purpose.